# Stack: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No operation deployProjectJsonMergeOption found on MBean io.fabric8:type=ProjectDeployer

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, fuseesb, fabric8

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ENTESB-8039?focusedCommentId=13618981&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-13618981

In above ticket it mentioned as resolved but when i tried in jboss fuse 6.3 latest version, it is not updating the profile. As a result it thrown below error.

Stack: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No operation deployProjectJsonMergeOption found on MBean io.fabric8:type=ProjectDeployer

Comment: If you have a Red Hat Fuse subscription then I suggest to use/ask via their custom portal to get support from the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using a more recent version of the maven plugin than Fuse, hence the exception. The deployProjectJsonMergeOption method was introduced in 6.3 Roll Up 1. I'd suggest using the same version plugin/fuse or upgrading your Fuse installation.

HTH,

John.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, we would like to use <overrideProfile>true</overrideProfile> feature in fabric 8 maven plugin(version 1.2.0.redhat-630346) for automation. I will inform to my client to get Roll up version 6.3.

Comment: Could you please let me know can we download roll up patches of fuse 6.3 in Redhat portal for learning purpose.

Comment: I think you can download them here : https://access.redhat.com/jbossnetwork/restricted/listSoftware.html?product=jboss.fuse&downloadType=patches&version=6.3 (needs a login)